# How do we create a proper working super_empty.img partition

Tags: android, super

If you have any information on how to create proper super_empty.img that would be great, been working on trying to create, but they never seem to work in my OTA. Thanks for the great work!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

make superimage_empty

See this [CL](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/433f822d76074943a7ab54de147be0889f4c3bef%5E%21/)